# How to hide a div inside a *ngFor loop

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular6

I want to add a form inside a *ngFor loop. Below is my attempt to repeat a button, like so: [image: What I want to acheive...]

#### html file:

```
<div *ngFor="let passenger of passengerForm;let i=index;">
  <form>
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" 
        [(ngModel)]="passenger.Name">
    </mat-form-field> 

  </Form>
  <div>
    <button (click)="addFieldValue(i); ">
      Add Passenger
    </button>
  </div>

</div>
```

#### typescript file:

```
newAttribute ={}
addFieldValue(index)  {

  if ( index < 3) {
    this.passengerForm.push(this.newAttribute )
    this.newAttribute = {};

  }
}
```

Comment: If the problem still exists then provide the stackblitz with expected output

Answer (score 1):

```
<div *ngFor="let passenger of passengerForm;let i=index;">
   <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" [(ngModel)]="passenger.Name">
</div>
```

Try this way. You need to wrap the input field only.